# Adding day to %t in orgmode capture template

Tags: org-mode

Complete novice here to Emacs and OrgMode. I've created a capture template (.txt file) that takes 1 task and returns a list of 3 subtasks that need to be completed. I have been able to get the template to request a schedule date for the subtask 1 using %^t.

Subtask 2 should be scheduled for the day following the first subtask. Is there a way of doing this simply in the .txt file? I've scoured the internet and tried various tricks but to no avail. I haven't yet figured out a way of making the date a variable and then modifying it in the .txt file. Here is the code currently in the .txt file:

```
* TODO %^{Task Name?}
** TODO SubTask 1
   SCHEDULED: %^{When schedule Subtask 1?}t
** TODO SubTask 2
   SCHEDULED: ;;would like this to be subtask1 date + 1 d;;
** TODO SubTask 3
```

Any help would be much appreciated - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
* TODO %^{Task Name?}
** TODO SubTask 1
   SCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t nil "When schedule Subtask 1?"))
** TODO SubTask 2
   SCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp (time-add (org-read-date nil t org-last-inserted-timestamp) (days-to-time 1)))
** TODO SubTask 3
```

Uses `%(EXP)` to evaluate an elisp expression EXP and replace it with the result. The first expressions prompts you for a date and inserts it. The seconds expressions uses the last inserted time stamp and adds one day.

You could also bind the time to a variable (`my-date`) locally and use that:

```
* TODO %^{Task Name?}
** TODO SubTask 1
   SCHEDULED: %(progn (setq-local my-date (org-read-date nil t nil "When schedule Subtask 1?")) (org-insert-time-stamp my-date))
** TODO SubTask 2
   SCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp (time-add my-date (days-to-time 1)))
** TODO SubTask 3
```

In the first expression it prompts for a date with `org-read-date` and bind it to my-date locally. Then it inserts the time timestamp. In the second expression one day is added to the time tuple bound to `my-date` and inserted as time stamp.

Comment: Heyo - thanks for helping out! Both of these above solutions produce the following: SCHEDULED: %![Error: (void-variable "When)] Any idea why I'm getting a void-variable?

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm. I'm guessing %(EXP) are evaluated first before anything else in the text file?

Comment: @user93377 From documentation "Since this happens after expanding non-interactive “%-escapes”, those can be used to fill the expression.". Non-interactive probably means without prompting in this context. This would mean after non-prompting and before prompting expansions.

Comment: So I'd have to write another %(EXP) phrase above if I wanted the "What's the name of this Task" asked first, I'm guessing.

Comment: Try it with `%(read-string "Task Name? ")` instead of `%^{Task Name?}`.

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you so much!